# Is curvature localised in General Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, curvature

Is the curvature of spacetime in General Relativy localised?

Answer (score 3):

The tensor of curvature is a function of the metric and its derivatives. The metric is a function of the point in space-time. So, as far as I understood the question, the curvature is localized, it is a function of $X^{\mu}$.